# rsync ssh file copying to GCE instance fails with permission denied

Tags: ssh, rsync, google-compute-engine

I'm executing the following on my local machine which is authenticated with my project in Google Compute Engine via the Google Cloud SDK:

```
rsync -avu --omit-dir-times -e ssh \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
    -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -i /home/fredrik/.ssh/google_compute_engine \
    /somefolder/hello.txt \
    1.2.3.4:/mymount/
```

...where `1.2.3.4` is the public IP of my GCE instance and I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

The machine I execute the command on is authenticated and can, e.g., successfully execute `gcloud compute ssh instance-1` in order to SSH into the same instance.

What do I need to do in order to successfully execute the rsync command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes around -e solved it:

```
rsync -avu --omit-dir-times -e "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/fredrik/.ssh/google_compute_engine" /somefolder/hello.txt 1.2.3.4:/mymount/
```

Comment: Does it still working on your computer? I can ssh but can not rsync to compute engine.